# How do I detect that I'm on the initial webView page?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, webkit, uinavigationbar

I have a `webView` in my app that works well. In order to enable the user to go back to the previous `url` `link` I have a custom back `button` in my `navigationBar`. Linked to that `button` is a simple code line that takes the user back to the previous screen:

```
-(void)webBackButton {
    NSLog(@"BACK BACK BACK");
    [_webView goBack];
}
```

Works great. Now the real issue here is that there obviously shouldn't be a back `button` in the initial `webView` (there's no place to go back to). So, I would like to hide and disable the `button` on the first `webView` shown. For that to happen I guess I need to somehow check to see that the current `webView` is not the initial `webView`. Like this:

```
if(!_webView.URL.absoluteURL) {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(webBackButton)];
}
```

And I suppose this check has to be done every time the ´webView`change its`url`path; that is when the user uses a`link`. If the current`webView`is`_webView.URL.absoluteURL`the back`button` should be hidden, otherwise it should be shown.

How do I accomplish this. As far as I understand, the `delegate` `webViewDidFinishLoad` is deprecated. I have tried using `observeValueForKeyPath` but it doesn't seem to trigger when I go to another `url`. Is there an easier way to hide the back `button` on the initial screen?

Answer (score 2):

UIWebview Class

```
open var canGoBack: Bool { get }
```

WKWebView Class

```
/** @abstract A Boolean value indicating whether there is a back item in
 the back-forward list that can be navigated to.
 @discussion @link WKWebView @/link is key-value observing (KVO) compliant
 for this property.
 @seealso backForwardList.
 */
open var canGoBack: Bool { get }
```

Add a check on webBackButton Method :

```
if([self.webView canGoBack]) {
    [backBtn setEnabled:YES];
} else {
    [backBtn setEnabled:NO];
}
```

> Sorry for mixing up Swift & Objective C, the pseudocode remains the same.

Comment: Ok, nice, but where do I put the check? It has to be triggered every time a webView url changes, which put me back to the delegate/observer part. Something needs to be triggered when navigation changes.

Comment: i would add a check on -(void)webBackButton{} method.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I'm not sure it makes sense to enable/show and disable/hide a button on the actual button click. Or am I misunderstanding you? webBackButton triggers the button click.